# Getting a subcomponent instance into an activity

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

**`AppComponent`**:

```
@PerApplication
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class))
interface AppComponent {
}
```

---

**`AppModule`**:

```
@Module(subcomponents = arrayOf(ActivityComponent::class))
class AppModule(private val context: Context) {

  @Provides @PerApplication
  fun provideContext() = context

  @Provides @PerApplication
  fun provideSharedPreferences(context: Context)
      = context.getSharedPreferences("${context.packageName}.preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

  @Provides @PerApplication
  fun provideMoshi() = Moshi.Builder().build()

  @Provides @PerApplication
  fun provideRetrofit(moshi: Moshi): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://reqres.in")
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
        .build()
  }
}
```

---

**`ActivityComponent`**:

```
@PerActivity
@Subcomponent(modules = arrayOf(ActivityModule::class))
interface ActivityComponent {

  fun inject(activity: MainActivity)

  @Subcomponent.Builder
  interface Builder {
    fun activityModule(module: ActivityModule): Builder
    fun build(): ActivityComponent
  }
}
```

---

**`ActivityModule`**:

```
@Module
class ActivityModule(private val activity: FragmentActivity) {

  @Provides @PerActivity
  fun provideActivity() = activity

  @Provides @PerActivity
  fun provideTestApi(retrofit: Retrofit) = retrofit.create(TestApi::class.java)
}
```

**How do I get a Builder instance of `ActivityComponent` into `MainActivity`?**

Activities are created by Dagger, so I can't inject a provider into the constructor like the example given in the [official docs](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html).

I tried to use the pre dagger-2.7 way of creating subcomponents by add the following line to `AppComponent`:

```
fun activityComponent(module: ActivityModule): ActivityComponent
```

and in `MainActivity`:

```
(application as App).appComponent.activityComponent(ActivityModule(this)).inject(this)
```

which gave me:

> Error:[com.example.injection.ActivityComponent.inject(com.example.modules.main.MainActivity)] com.example.api.TestApi cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

Comment: Im having the same issue. Have you figured out the error?